# MongoDB join 2 tables and select field is null

Tags: mongodb, meteor, object-oriented-database

In MongoDB

I have a job sign up application. I have two collections- `Jobs` and `HelperJobs`. 
The first collection contains all the jobs and the second maps Helpers to the jobs they signed up for.

I want to select all of the jobs that the current logged in user has not signed up for. So the following code works to bring back a collection of the intersection of all jobs and helper jobs but I want it to only return a collection where another field (hours) is null.

```
db.jobs.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "helperjobs",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "job",
    as: "temp"
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) after the $lookup using the `temp.hours` field to filter on:

```
db.jobs.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "helperjobs",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "job",
    as: "temp"
  },
  {
    $match: { "temp.hours": { $exists:false } }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Looks like ... { $eq: null }} is not returning when I run this directly on Mongo. I replaced it with "temp.hours": { $exists:false} which does the trick on Mongo.. I have some further code issue in Meteor to work out but this gets me over the query issue - thanks

Comment: Good call I updated the answer. Did not test and just wrote by memory